# java-Executor Framework

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

Please look at my following code....

```
  private static final int NTHREDS = 10;
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
  while(rs.next()){
            webLink=rs.getString(1);
            FirstName=rs.getString(2);
            MiddleName=rs.getString(3);
            Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(webLink,FirstName,MiddleName);// this interface has run method....
            executor.execute(worker); 

   }
```

//added

```
      public class MyRunnable implements Runnable  {


      MyRunnable(String webLink,String FirstName,String MiddleName){
         ** Assigning Values...***
      }

      @Override

      public void run() {

      long sum = 0;

      **Calling method to crawl by passing those Values**

      try {

      Thread.sleep(200);

      } 

      catch (InterruptedException e)

      {

      e.printStackTrace();

      }

      }

     }
```

In this part if the resultset(**rs**) having 100 records excutor creating 100 threads..... I need to run this process with in 10 threads. I need your help to know how to get control of threads.. If any thread has completed its task then it should process the immediate available task from the Result Set. Is it possible to achieve using executor framework.

Thanks...

vijay365

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  What is resultset?  What are `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `webLink`?  What are your requirements?  Executors can do lots of things, you need to be more precise.  Offer some more specific code, and what you want to happen, and I'm sure I/we can provide some example code to help you.

Comment: Seems like this would already do what you're asking. If you passed the values from the ResultSet into the Runnable, then executed each, say your ResultSet returned 100 rows, then you would create 100 Runnables, and the executor would push those through your 10 threads. Effectively, as one Runnable completed, the next one (with a differ row) would be run. Isn't this what you're after? If not, maybe tell us what the output is that you're seeing and you would like it to be.

Comment: hi Melv Thanks for ur reply ... basically this is a krawler tool. navigating the link then finding firstname.middlename of a person if matched the program will copy the url... This is the process. I tried to pass these fields as parameters of runnables... but the result set comes to end and showing error sorry i can remember that error.

Comment: hi andersoj , This is vijay... I added some codes ... Please take a look at my question and post your suggestions if possible...

Comment: So basically if firstname is "X" and middlename is "Y" then you want to return a url is it. You want to get a list of url after scanning all rows. Am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

The code you've already posted does this.  Your code will not immediately spawn 100 threads.  It will spawn 10 threads that consume tasks from a queue containing your Runnables.

From the [Executors.newFixedThreadPool Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29):

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a
>   fixed set of threads operating off a
>   shared unbounded queue.

Instead of using a static number of threads (10 in this case) you should determine the number dynamically:

```
    final int NTHREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Also, I don't get why you are calling `Thread.sleep`?

Answer (score 1):

ResultSet is probably a JDBC query result.

This design is almost certain to be doomed to failure.

The JDBC interface implementations are not thread-safe.

ResultSets are scare resources that should be closed in the same scope in which they were created.  If you pass them around, you're asking for trouble.

Multi-threaded code is hard to write well and even harder to debug if incorrect.

You are almost certainly headed in the wrong direction with this design.  I'd bet a large sum of money that you're guilty of premature optimization.  You are hoping that multiple threads will make your code faster, but what will happen is ten threads time slicing on one CPU and taking the same time or longer.  (Context switching takes time, too.)

A slightly better idea would be to load the ResultSet into an object or collection, close the ResultSet, and then do some multi-threaded processing on that returned object.

Comment: Hi duffymo, thanks for your reply... but am little bit confusing due am beginner on using this concept. I could'nt control the flow . I tried in many ways ...could u let me know in detail. Can u show some part of logic if possible. ??

Answer (score 0):

Try `executor.submit(worker);`